# C linked-list append to head or tail?

Tags: c, insert, linked-list, macros

I am looking at this code, implementing an insert operation of an element in a doubly linked-list. I am trying to grasp why the `LIST_APPEND` macro appends it to the end of the list, however, I always explain it to myself to be at the head. Code:

```
struct link {
    struct link *prev;
    struct link *next;
};

void insert(struct link *prev, struct link *new, struct link *next)
{
    prev->next = new;
    new->prev = prev;
    next->prev = new;
    new->next = next;
}

#define LIST_APPEND(member, list, new)    \
    insert(list.prev, &(new->member), &list)
```

My considerations:

Firstly, after the C-Preprocessor replaces the macro's content in the actual code, we get

```
void insert(list.prev, &(new->member), &list)
{
    (list.prev)->next = (new->member);    //1.
    (new->member)->prev = list.prev;      //2.
    list->prev = (new->member);           //3.
    (new->member)->next = list;           //4.
}
```

Which corresponds to:
1. The `next` of `list.prev` points to `(new->member)`
2. The `prev` of `(new->member)` is now `list.prev`
3. The `prev` of `list` is now `(new->member)`
4. The next of `(new->member)` is `list`

If I had flows in my logic, they could have been here.

Now to illustrate it, here is a possible (to my understanding) depiction of the insertion.

[image: linked-list]

**Question**: After all, is the append at the head or at the tail? If the latter where am I wrong?

Comment: could you provide an example of how you call the macro? What do you pass as "member"?

Comment: You should protect macro arguments in the expansion: `#define LIST_APPEND(member, list, new)   insert((list).prev, &((new)->member), &(list))

Comment: "Firstly, after the C-Preprocessor replaces the macro's content in the actual code, we get ..." - no?? The preprocessor doesn't change `insert`. It changes `LIST_APPEND(a, b, c)` into `insert(b.prev, &(c->a), &b)`.

Comment: @immibis Yes, of course. That is what I said (*meant*). `insert` is already defined. It just calls it with the macro parameters

Comment: Completely off topic, but suggest you don't call variables `new` since that is a C++ keyword. You're just causing confusion and digging a hole if you want to move to C++ in the future.

Comment: @user8 The macro is weird. Please add an usage example in your question!

Comment: Why are list.prev and list.next divided into two parts in your diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you have given above

```
struct link {
struct link *prev;
struct link *next;
};

void insert(struct link *prev, struct link *new, struct link *next)
{
prev->next = new;
new->prev = prev;
next->prev = new;
new->next = next;
}

#define LIST_APPEND(member, list, new)    \
insert(list.prev, &(new->member), &list)
```

here the `insert(struct link *prev, struct link *new, struct link *next)`function is inserting a new node in between the prev node and in next node.

Here in `insert()` function `struct link *prev, struct link *new, struct link *next` are pointer variable of type `struct link`

And in a doubly linked list it is not necessary to append node at head or tail. It is totally depend on the programmers choice where to append a new node in doubly linked list.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that the enclosing structure is empty("list" in the macro), so that it really is as the picture shows, but since "list" is empty is tail. The next element will be "prev" of "new->member". In short, it really depends on the usage. Lesson learned.